# Is is possible to estimate the distribution by drawing observations?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I want to estimate how many red balls in a box. Red, yellow, blue balls could be in the box. But I don't know how many of them are in the box.

What I did was randomly drawing 10 balls from the box and learned that there was no red ball.

(Edit: Assume the number of the balls in the box is a known finite number. Let's say 10,000)

Can I say the possibility of having at least one red ball is $$\left(\frac13\right)^{10}= 0.00169\ \%\ ?$$ (3 possible outcomes, and 10 observations)

I'm thinking I don't know the distribution of the colors of the balls, so I'm not sure this inference is reasonable or not. Thanks!

Comment: Even if you knew there were equal numbers of each color in the box with replacement, your equation would still not be correct. At least one red ball means anything from 1 to 10. The correct equation would be $1-(\frac{2}{3})^{10} = .9827$

Comment: Statistical hypothesis testing requires some kind of probability model for the null hypothesis. That is lacking here. If you are told that there are 30 balls in the box and that either 0 or 10 of them are red, then you can make 10 as your null hypothesis. If your data consist of 10 balls drawn without replacement, then you have a hypergeometric model for the null hyp. based on 10 red and 20 non-red. The probability of seeing X = 0 red balls under the null hyp. is ${20\choose 10}/{30\choose 10} \approx 0.006.$ In those circumstances you might reject the null hyp, and conclude 0 red in box.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant say that.

> Infinite case:

The reason is that you dont know how many balls there are in a box in total.  For instance, it may be that a box contains infinite number of balls (since we are talking about mathematical box, I can make this assumption) $\frac{9}{10}$'th of which are red.  In this case, the probability of drawing at least $1$ red ball out of $10$ is will be different from what you calculated.

> Finite case:

Similar argument applies.  If it happens that the true distribution of balls are such that the share of red balls is $9/10$, then your above calculation is not correct.

Comment: Understood the infinite case. What if the number of the balls in the box is known a finite number?

Comment: @MarcusThornton The same argument applies: suppose the share of red balls is $9/10$, but the number of balls are finite.  Importantly, you need to assume a prior distribution of the share of red colored balls in the box, and your result will depend on that prior

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: The answer to the title of your question is, "Yes, but not with anywhere near the kind of accuracy and confidence you seem to be asking for."

---

Let's say I put $10000$ balls in a box, and exactly one of the balls is red.
You know the total number of balls but not how many there are of each color.

You draw $5000$ balls without replacement and look at each one to see if it is red.
I then ask you whether there was a red ball in the box before you started taking balls out, and you answer "yes" or "no."

If your criterion for "no red ball" is that none of the balls you drew were red, then there is a $50\%$ chance you will give me the wrong answer.

Now consider the case where you draw only $10$ balls. If you think getting only yellow and blue balls in the first ten is enough to say that there is *not* at least one red ball in the box, what's the probability that you'll give the wrong answer in the case where there actually *is* exactly one red ball in the box?

Note that it doesn't matter how many other colors there are. You'll get wrong answers just as likely when we fill the rest of the box with balls of $100$ different colors as when we use only yellow and blue balls in addition to the red ball.

---

Trying to decide there are *no* individuals of type X in a large population is something you basically cannot resolve simply by examining a small sample.
The formula you give would be a reasonable one to use if the question you are trying to answer is, "Are at least $\frac23$ of the balls red?"
(And even then, I would not describe your result as the *probability* that the answer is "yes".)